# send images from pc to android

Tags: java, c#, android, image

I'm trying to write an application that creates images on the PC and transmits over WiFi and displays it on an Android. I have everything working except the last part.  The Android and PC are sending messages back and forth. The PC creates images, converts it to a byte array, sends it to the Android, Android receives it. The thing that doesn't work is converting the byte array back to an image. Here is my code.

The C# code on my PC uses this to create the byte array

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

The Java code on my Android uses this code to convert the byte array back to an image.

```
try {
    //This line always returns NULL
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    if (bmp != null) {
        //display image in UI
        imgViewer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imgViewer.invalidate();
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(Consts.TAG, "image is null ");
    }                   
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.i(Consts.TAG, "ERROR decoding image " + e.toString());
}
```

`BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` always returns NULL. Am I creating the byte array correctly on the PC? Should I be recreating the image differently on the Android?

Comment: If `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp` will create a BMP format picture, then the problem is that Android does not understand that. Try png or jpg.

Comment: have you checked to see if the byte array is null on the android side?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I needed to convert the image like this. Now it works.

```
    public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

Thanks to zapl and FoamyGuy for your input.